# What regex should be used to filter the first three words on each line

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say i have an output that looks like this:

```
04 12 2014 145 15
04 12 2014 180 05
04 12 2014 141 65
```

I want to parse somehow only the dates to look like this
`04 12 2014 
 04 12 2014
 04 12 2014`.

In order to clarify for what situation i need this, I am trying to extract some dates from a website and see if there is a recent one added.

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='searchResult']/tr/td/font[@class='detDesc']"))
        {
            string input =  node.InnerHtml.ToString();
            //The [^0-9] expression is used to find any character that is NOT a digit, will replace with empty string
            input = Regex.Replace(input, "([^0-9]+)"," ");

            //populate list with input
            uploadList.Add(input);
            Console.WriteLine(input);
        }
```

I've tried several times but this was the best data form that i can reach. Can anyone guide me in order to understand please?

Thank you

Comment: Split each value e.g. 04 12 2014 145 15 via a space, the re-combine the 1st 3 elements and convert back to a date

Comment: Does it mean you have `04 12 2014 145 15` in the `input` after the `Regex.Replace`? What is the value of `node.InnerHtml.ToString()`? Note you may adjust `input = Regex.Replace(input, "([^0-9]+)"," ");` to actually get the necessary result, so you do not need to add any additional regex or LINQ code.

Comment: yes, if you want i can provide the output before Regex.Replace

Comment: Yes, please because it can shorten the code and make additional lines of code unnecessary.

Comment: It looks like this:
`Uploaded 11-03&nbsp;2015, Size 2.23&nbsp;GiB, ULed by <a class="detDesc" href="/
user/.BONE./" title="Browse .BONE.">.BONE.</a>` on 30 rows. I can't post the whole output due to comment limitations.

Comment: It is enough... Try `string input  = Regex.Replace(node.InnerHtml.ToString(), @"(?s)^.*?(\d{2})\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{4}).*", "$1 $2 $3");`. See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%5e.*%3f%28%5cd%7b2%7d%29%5cD*%28%5cd%7b2%7d%29%5cD*%28%5cd%7b4%7d%29.*&i=Uploaded+11-03%26nbsp%3b2015%2c+Size+2.23%26nbsp%3bGiB%2c+ULed+by+%3ca+class%3d%22detDesc%22+href%3d%22%2f+user%2f.BONE.%2f%22+title%3d%22Browse+.BONE.%22%3e.BONE.%3c%2fa%3e&r=%241+%242+%243).

Comment: I posted the answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following lines:

```
string input =  node.InnerHtml.ToString();
//The [^0-9] expression is used to find any character that is NOT a digit, will replace with empty string
input = Regex.Replace(input, "([^0-9]+)"," ");
```

with

```
string input = Regex.Replace(node.InnerHtml.ToString(), @"(?s)^.*?(\d{2})\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{4}).*", "$1 $2 $3");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%5E.%2A%3F%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%5CD%2A%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%5CD%2A%28%5Cd%7B4%7D%29.%2A&i=Uploaded%2011-03%26nbsp%3B2015%2C%20Size%202.23%26nbsp%3BGiB%2C%20ULed%20by%20%3Ca%20class%3D%22detDesc%22%20href%3D%22%2F%20user%2F.BONE.%2F%22%20title%3D%22Browse%20.BONE.%22%3E.BONE.%3C%2Fa%3E&r=%241%20%242%20%243).

The pattern matches:

- `(?s)` - Enables the `RegexOptions.Singleline` mode when `.` matches any char
- `^` - start of a string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars up to the first...
- `(\d{2})` - capturing group 1 (referred to via `$1` from the replacement pattern): two digits
- `\D*` - 0+ chars other than digits
- `(\d{2})` - capturing group 2 (referred to via `$2` from the replacement pattern): two digits
- `\D*` - 0+ chars other than digits
- `(\d{4})` - capturing group 3 (referred to via `$3` from the replacement pattern): four digits
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?:\S+\s+){2}\S+).*
```

with this regex you'll get first three words of string

or

If you have only spaces between words  split by \s+. When you split, the array would be the words themselves. First three would be in arr[0], arr[1] and arr[3] if you do:

```
String[] arr = origString.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Not sure you noticed, but the question is tagged with C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to get the first part `[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}`